# How Composite subrequests count toward ConnectAPI limits

Tags: rest-api, limits, composite

I´m using Salesforce [batch composite API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm)

```
{
"batchRequests" : [
    {
    "method" : "PATCH",
    "url" : "v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ",
    "richInput" : {"Name" : "NewName"}
    },{
    "method" : "GET",
    "url" : "v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ"
    }]
```

}

and i'm facing error:
**"You have reached the Connect API's hourly request limit for this user and application' error"**

This error occurs when you exceed the ConnectAPI limit of 2000 batches per user, per hour. [Salesforce help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316318&type=1&mode=1)

How Salesforce is counting the number of batches?Is it so that each subrequest is one batch call?

The API call example above is consuming one or two (2 subrequests) calls from the limit of 2000 Connect API batches per user per hour?

Comment: The help article on the API limit is a bit confusing (at least to me). The error message in there says API's hourly request limit and then the following statement says ConnectAPI limit of 2000 batches.

Comment: Same here, would be good to clarify this topic. Can´t find any useful help article,

Comment: did you run a simple experiment of submitting 80 batchRequests, each of size 25 subrequests = 2000 subrequests and then submit one more batchRequest (_all in the same clock hour_)? if that fails, then the limit is on subrequests.  But the doc seems to point at 2000 batches, not 2000 subrequests

Comment: I run the experiment you suggested: the limit is on 2000 batches, not 2000 subrequests.Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution running the experiment @copredy suggested with a comment: "submitting 80 batchRequests, each of size 25 subrequests = 2000 subrequests and then submit one more batchRequest (all in the same clock hour)? if that fails, then the limit is on subrequests"

**SOLUTION:** The limit is 2000 batches, not 2000 subrequests.